# Bi monthly recuring tasks in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is it possible to register a recuring task in Outlook, that happens the first day of every second month.

Or would these have to be registered individually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Select "Recurrence pattern: **Monthly**" and 
"Day **1** of every **2** months".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Recurrence, every 2 weeks:

[image]

Comment: -1, they want it two repeat every two months, *not* approximately twice a month.

Comment: @DMA57361 what do you mean by "two repeat?"

Comment: D'oh, typo, used the wrong to/too/two. It should read "...they want it *to* repeat every..."